# Change values of dynamically added controls in winform c#.net application, how to track dynamically added controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, dynamically-generated

I have added controls dynamically on runtime inside the rows of a tableLayoutpanel , the controls added are LABELS, LINKLABEL AND A PICTURE BOX.

Now , i want to change the value(Text Property) of these dynamically added controls(Labels, Linklabels) to some specified value,  on a button click.

How do i do this? Please help with code.

Is there some kind of ID for these dynamically controls like we have in HTML.

Also , am trying to use this but all in vain...........

```
Control[] GettableLayoutPanelControls = new Control[11];

          GettableLayoutPanelControls =  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("Control Name", true) ;

             GettableLayoutPanelControls.SetValue("CHANGED VALUE ", 0); //this line gives error..........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, which will add 11 new text boxes (or any other control you want):

```
int NumberOfTextBoxes = 11;
TextBox[] DynamicTextBoxes = new TextBox[NumberOfTextBoxes];
int ndx = 0;

while (ndx < NumberOfTextBoxes) 
{
    DynamicTextBoxes[ndx] = new TextBox();
    DynamicTextBoxes[ndx].Name = "TextBox" + ndx.ToString();
    // You can set TextBox value here:
    // DynamicTextBoxes[ndx].Text = "My Value";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(DynamicTextBoxes[ndx]);
    ndx++;
}
```

This will dynamically add Text Boxes to your TableLayout control. If you need to retreive them later:

```
foreach (Control c in TableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox TextBoxControl = (TextBox)c;

        // This will modify the value of the 3rd text box we added
        if (TextBoxControl.Name.Equals("TextBox3"))      
            TextBoxControl.Text = "My Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: @icemanind : sir, can i also get the controls row wise? that is , i want to get the controls in the ROW 1 of tableLayoutPanel, set their new values, then get the ROW 2 controls ..........and so on......is this possible?

Comment: @icemanind : also , is giving different Names to all the dynamic controls necessary , can i not give the same Name and access them and set different values for each of them, sir?

Comment: @sqlchild - Accessing the controls through rows and columns are a bit more tricky because the TableLayoutPanel dynamically changes its rows and columns depending on the size. For example, the control that's at row 2, column 1, may be a different control on someone else's machine. It may be at row 1, column 4, for example.

Comment: TextBox TextBoxControl = (TextBox)c;  ----- sir, can you please explain me this line of code, as am a beginner, so need it!

Comment: @icemanind :TextBox TextBoxControl = (TextBox)c; ----- sir, can you please explain me this line of code, as am a beginner, so need it!

Comment: Yeah. You are creating a TextBoxControl variable and assigning it the TextBox Control. The "(TextBox)c" part of it is called a cast. Because the variable "c" is a Control object, it needs to be converted into a TextBox variable. Casting is what does it. Though realize, its not really converting it. It is simply telling C# that this object is a TextBox.

Comment: @icemanind : but sir, you din't use TextBoxControl variable anywhere, which is created in this step: TextBox TextBoxControl = (TextBox)c --------then why was this step done?

Comment: I just updated the example. I made a mistake. Sorry about that. Look at the revised code now. After declaring TextBoxControl, I went ahead and used that instead of the "c" variable.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to keep track of the dynamically created controls in a private field.

```
private Label _myLabel;
_myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "Hello World!";
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
// ... later in the button click handler ... //
myLabel.Text = "Goodbye Cruel World!";
```

Remember, Windows Forms is a stateful environment, unlike ASP.NET, so fields don't lose their values when the user interacts with the form.

ETA:

```
Label dynamic_label = new Label();
for(in i =0;i<6;i++){this.Controls.Add(dynamic_label);}
```

This code from your comment adds the SAME label 5 times. I don't think that's your intent. When you set the Text property they will all have the same text because they reference the same control. You can use my solution and declare

```
Label myLabel1, myLabel2, ..., myLabel5;
```

If you have so many that you're declaring them in a loop then I would store them in a `Dictionary<string, Label>` so that you don't have to search the array to find the correct one.

Comment: i have done this method which you have told, but there are five LABELS , with the same name, and i want to set different values for each to something specified on a button click.

Comment: I did this : Label dynamic_label = new Label(); --- for(in i =0;i<6;i++){this.Controls.Add(dynamic_label);}