# How do i make each individual button/checkbox in a 5x5 button array have a different event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, eventhandler

I have this chunk of code...

```
public void initButtons(CheckBox[,] buttons)
    {
        int locX = 0;
        int locY = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < buttons.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < buttons.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                buttons[x, y] = new CheckBox();
                buttons[x, y].Appearance = Appearance.Button;
                buttons[x, y].Location = new Point(locX, locY);
                buttons[x, y].Size = new Size(60, 60);
                buttons[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.MemoryButton_Clicked);
                this.Controls.Add(buttons[x, y]);

                locX += 60; 
            }
            locX = 0;
            locY += 60;
        }
    }
```

...which creates a 5x5 grid of checkboxes. I would like each individual button to have a different EventHandler (instead of all buttons sharing the same one). Is this possible?

Comment: Make an array of `EventHandler` with one for each of your buttons

Comment: btw is this wpf or winforms ?

Comment: You can use `Sender` for this purpose check this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528628/2946329

Comment: @gogaz This is winforms

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes ? even your array is named `buttons`

Comment: what do you want to be different about the event handler?

Comment: @gogaz This is used for a memory game project. When the user presses on the button it shows an image. When 3 buttons are pressed (and the images don't match) all checkboxes go back to "unpressed" state.

Comment: You should definetly use buttons instead of checkboxes, but this has nothing to see with your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda expression to make an anonymous function your event handler

```
buttons[x, y].Click += new EventHandler((s, ea) =>
{
    //insert code here;
});
```

Doing this uses closures, so you can do neat things like the following.

```
buttons[x, y].Click += new EventHandler((s, ea) =>
{
    var aString = String.Format("my coordinates are {0} and {1}", x, y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i fixed it. Basically i just add buttons[x,y].Name="Button"+i; and i++; in the forloop. Each element in the 2d array gets a unique name and i can use .Name.Equals later if i want to call it.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511194/7024105